# how to make objects point in the direction they are travelling With Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I would like the objects to face the direction they are moving in.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Moving objects pointing to the movement direction]

What I did was calculate the next position along with the current and use those two to create a direction vector.

[image: Geometry Nodes]

You may need another Axis in the *Aling Euler to Vector* node.

I'm not very happy with this solution because there may be a obvious method to do this that doesn't require two similar calculations... or maybe there isn't. To this moment, i didn't think of another way.